# How can I make my Brother DCP-J315W scanner work on Ubuntu 17.10, 19.10 and 20.04?

Tags: 17.10, 19.10, 20.04, scanner, brother

How can I make my Brother DCP-J315W scanner work on Ubuntu 17.10, 19.10 and 20.04?

---

After a fresh install of Ubuntu, try...

**Don't forget to turn on your DCP-J315W and connect it to the USB port.**

Install any new updates:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Install `sane` and (only for Ubuntu 17.10) `libsane-extras`:

```
sudo apt-get install sane
sudo apt-get install libsane-extras
```

Install `libusb-0.1-4`:

```
sudo apt-get install libusb-0.1-4
```

Download `linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.1-1` script here (Driver Install Tool link):

```
http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=es&lang=es&prod=dcpj315w_eu_as&os=128&flang=English
```

Gunzip the file:

```
gunzip linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.1-1.gz
```

Run the script as root and when asking for DeviceURI, choose No.

```
sudo -i
bash linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.1-1 DCP-J315W
exit
```

Copy libs to the needed folders:

```
sudo cp /usr/lib64/sane/* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane
sudo cp -r /usr/lib64/* /usr/lib
```

At this stage the scanner should work. If not, try to reboot.

**These commands should return output shown:**

```
$ sane-find-scanner
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04f9 [Brother], product=0x0254 [DCP-J315W]) at libusb:002:005
```

---

```
$ brscan-skey
$ brscan-skey -l
DCP-J315W         : brother3:bus1;dev2  : USB                  Active
```

---

```
$ scanimage -L
device `brother3:bus1;dev2' is a Brother DCP-J315W USB scanner
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Nice tutorial but this a Q&A site. You should divide it into a question and an answer, the answer being what you just posted as question.

Comment: You should make this top part being a questions and post your solution as an answer, this is how the site works. Voting to opening it so you can make your change properly.

Comment: When you post your answer after the question is reopened, could you add a link to where we can download the installer script please?